# While inserting values to date field getting exception

Tags: sql, datetime, constraints

**While inserting the value to date field in POP10100 table getting the exception like this**:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the CHECK constraint
>   "CK_*POP10100*_DISCDA__009508B4". The
>   conflict occurred in database "TWO",
>   table "dbo.POP10100", column
>   'DISCDATE'. The statement has been
>   terminated. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)

**When i checked that 'DISCDATE' field it written like this:**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POP10100]  WITH CHECK 
  ADD CHECK  ((datepart(hour,[DISCDATE])=(0) 
             AND datepart(minute,[DISCDATE])=(0) 
             AND datepart(second,[DISCDATE])=(0) 
             AND datepart(millisecond,[DISCDATE])=(0)))
```

Could somebody pls elaborate what does this check constraint saying, i mean how can i pass the discount date value to avoid the above exception. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[`datepart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) returns a part of the given datetime.

Thus, it's ensuring that the hour, minute, second, and millisecond values are all equal to zero.

Update: Instead of just passing in your DateTime as is, use the Date property. 
eg:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Comment: @Will Hughes: hi am using e-connect stored procedure in that there is an input paramater UpdateIfexits(type small int), how can i handle this from C#, any help pls..

Comment: Is the stored procedure setting the date value, or is it passed as a parameter from C#?   Can you modify the stored procedure or only the C# code?

Comment: @Sparky: i can not modify the SP, i can see the paramater only and passing those parameter from C#.

Comment: Are you passing the date as part of the procedure call?   If so, use the C#   ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") method to strip the time portion out of the date parameter.   If you are not passing the date, then someone needs to modify the stored proc to truncate the time portion out of the date value written to the database

Comment: @Sparky The correct method for getting just the Date from a DateTime is to call the Date property.

Comment: Thanks Will, I tend to use the ToString to get more control over the format, but the Date method probably works better for this example...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will only accept a date that has a time of midnight (00:00:00).  This is probably because until SQL Server 2008, there was no data type that only held a date value, it would hold a date and time value.

Comment: s: hi am using e-connect stored procedure in that there is an input paramater UpdateIfexits(type small int), how can i handle this from C#, any help pls..

Comment: If it is the small int that is being converted into a date time, then you'll have to look to see how the stored procedure is doing it as there isn't a straight conversion from small int to date time.  Small int in c# is short.  You can try what Will Hughs suggested and pass int the Date property of your DateTime and see if that works.